# Good SQLite wrapper for objective C

Tags: objective-c, ios, sqlite

I need good sqlite wrapper. Now I use BWDB I get it from video course by Lynda.com but I have problem with it when I try to insert something. DB is locked and I don't know how to unlock it. Please give me some fast wrapper with good documentation. Best regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One could use sqlite directly in ObjectiveC but since it gets ugly pretty fast, [**FMDB**](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/03/fmdb_for_iphone.html), [**is a**](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), [**good wrapper**](http://gusmueller.com/blog/archives/2008/06/new_home_for_fmdb.html) for sqlite.

Its good in my opinion. But you might also want to look at [**Core data**](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). Core Data is infamous for its steep learning curve but once you get a hang of it it's pretty neat...

Comment: ... pretty neat and has the best system level integration of anything, core data does.

Comment: … not using Core Data often means ending up with implementing your own flawed version of Core Data.

Comment: It's like lots of things with tight integration.  Apple assumes they know better than you, and messes it up so you can't use an sqlite DB from someplace else.

Comment: But sqlite seems easier to prepopulate than Core Data. I know you can hack into the sqlite DB that Core Data uses, but I don't think you're supposed to do that.

Comment: yes you are right, either go completely coreData route or use sqlite directly with some objecticeC wrapper on top.

Answer (score 3):

Use [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb). it is the best in my opinion.

Comment: I see 86 open issues, in their GitHub repo.. is this still usable for production apps

Comment: yes I have few apps submitted to app store.